# Estimating Netty client's throughput

Tags: netty

I have following setup. [image]

Netty Server is receiving traffic from a 3rd party client over 10G link. I have to forward this traffic to other host using Netty client over a 1G link.
Does netty have any API which I can use to estimate the write speed of my Netty Client (1G link) so I can use this information to limit bandwidth of my Netty Server (10G link) ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to use TCP backpressure, which means your proxy doesn't read more than it can write. This is achieved by sending TCP ACK signal only once you are ready to receive more.

An approach based only on throughput measurement is not suitable because it does not deal with a temporary degradation. (Such a measurement is trivial to achieve by counting the size of buffers in a sliding time window.)

Netty offers an API for TCP backpressure, which is what you need. You "just" have to turn automatic read with `ChannelOption.AUTO_READ` set to `false` and call `Channel.read()` explicitely, after the write succeeded.

I suggest that you have a close look at [Netty's sample proxy](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.java), which disables `AUTO_READ`.

[LittleProxy](https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy) is a more complex piece of code, which also monitors the throughput.